# Function from external js link not working Properly On Mean.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, meanjs

Can anyone help me with this problem?

OKay im using Mean.js(Im a newb) and on my home controller im trying to call my Jquery dependencies witch came with the tamplate i bought.
This is the code im using.

```
'use strict';angular.module('core').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'Authentication',
function($scope, $http, $location, Authentication) {
    // This provides Authentication context.
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;
    if (!$scope.authentication.user) $location.path('/signin');
        $scope.inicio = function(){ 
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {  

            App.setPage("index");
            App.init(); 
            });
        };  
}]);

And calling my JS from config/env/all.js and here is it
'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
            'public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
            'public/lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js',
            'public/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
            'public/tema/js/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js',
            'public/tema/bootstrap-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/uniform/jquery.uniform.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/backstretch/jquery.backstretch.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/bootstrap-daterangepicker/moment.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/jQuery-slimScroll-1.3.0/jquery.slimscroll.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/jQuery-slimScroll-1.3.0/slimScrollHorizontal.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/jQuery-BlockUI/jquery.blockUI.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/sparklines/jquery.sparkline.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/easypiechart/jquery.easypiechart.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/flot/jquery.flot.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/flot/jquery.flot.time.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/flot/jquery.flot.selection.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/flot/jquery.flot.resize.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/flot/jquery.flot.pie.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/flot/jquery.flot.stack.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/flot/jquery.flot.crosshair.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/jquery-todo/js/paddystodolist.js',
            'public/tema/js/timeago/jquery.timeago.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/jQuery-Cookie/jquery.cookie.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/gritter/js/jquery.gritter.min.js',
            'public/tema/js/script.js',
```

Some dependencies do work but some dont its very wierd, and if i call it from console(Google chrome) everything works fine but cant make it work from the controller.
Im sorry my english is bad..
And thanks for the help

Comment: You shouldn't call Jquery from an Angular Controller, you should use instead a directive to do Dom manipulation and possible not with Jquery. What's `App`?

Comment: App is a javascript function from 'public/tema/js/script.js', witch initialize the plugins needed for the page